# Function overloading with template and constant pointer

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I want a generic function which takes a template and some specialization via function overloading. However the wrong function is called when using the keyword constant or using a pointer.
What I want is:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void myFunction(const T variable){
    std::cout << "Generic called";
}

void myFunction(const Eigen::MatrixXd* variable){
    std::cout << "Eigen matrix overload";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Eigen::MatrixXd my_variables;
    myFunction(&my_variables);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints "Generic called". While I would expect it to call the overload.

I already played around a little. Without the const keyword I get the expected behaviour:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void myFunction(T variable){
    std::cout << "Generic called";
}

void myFunction(Eigen::MatrixXd* variable){
    std::cout << "Eigen matrix overload";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Eigen::MatrixXd my_variables;
    myFunction(&my_variables);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints "Eigen matrix overload" as expected.
And without the pointer:

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void myFunction(const T variable){
    std::cout << "Generic called";
}

void myFunction(const Eigen::MatrixXd variable){
    std::cout << "Eigen matrix overload";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Eigen::MatrixXd my_variables;
    myFunction(my_variables);
    return 0;
}
```

Also print "Eigen matrix overload".

So why does the first example not print "Eigen matrix overload"?

EDIT:
I found that putting the const after the pointer does call the correct function  but that makes my pointer const and I (also) want my object constant.

```cpp
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void myFunction(const T variable){
    std::cout << "Generic called";
}

void myFunction(Eigen::MatrixXd* const variable){
    std::cout << "Eigen matrix overload";
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Eigen::MatrixXd my_variables;
    myFunction(&my_variables);
    return 0;
}
```

Using `void myFunction(const Eigen::MatrixXd* const variable)` again calls the generic function.

EDIT2:
The answer of blindcrone explains why the first option calls the generic function. But with that explanation I would expect the generic would also be called in my third code block (with const but not a pointer and also for the case similar to the third code block but with the argument as a reference). Could someone also explain that?

Comment: It doesn't do what you want because `const` in `const T` does nothing for overload resolution, and `T` is a perfect match for everything, while `const Eigen::MatrixXd*` is not a perfect match for `Eigen::MatrixXd*`.. Perhaps you meant to write `const T*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're overloading the function, you're relying on the type of the variable passed to the function to invoke the right one. Your template function covers any type that isn't of the exact type *const Eigen::MatrixXd**

So in your first example, you're calling *myFunction* with the argument *&my_variables*. Since *my_variables* is of the type *Eigen::MatrixXd*, that means that *&my_variables* is of the type *Eigen::MatrixXd**.

In C++'s type system, the const qualifier changes the type for the purposes of a function parameter. So in your first example, you are calling the generic because there is no overload for a non-const pointer of that type. Often when there is no better candidate for a function overload, a non-const type can be implicitly cast to the corresponding const type in this situation, so you may be used to being able to call functions whose parameters are declared const with variables which were not, but since there is an available generic for this function, the compiler simply chose the generic one, because the function signature fit the call with no cast necessary.

Comment: Uhm yes I understand. Meanwhile I played a bit further and if I change my function to take a const reference (`void myFunction(const Eigen::MatrixXd &variable`) then it does call the correct function. With your explanation I would think it would then still chose the wrong function. Could you also explain that?

Comment: @C.Binair you changed it to take a reference and changed the call to  `myFunction(my_variables)` ? (ie no &)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes I also changed the call

Comment: Additionally to my first comment, I also don't understand with this explanation why my third option without the pointer does work. In that case you give `Eigen::MatrixXd` while function requires `const Eigen::MatrixXd`. So in that case you would also need an implicit conversion to make it const